# Return RGB value from given value of 0-100 with custom RGB scale

Tags: c#, rgb

I am looking to return a RGB value from a given value from 0 - 100 using a custom RGB scale like this:

```
RANGE   Ra      Ga      Ba      Rb      Gb      Bb
0       255     255     255     255     255     255
0-1     165     242     243     125     200     255
1-25    0       255     0       63      82      0
25-50   63      82      0       255     143     31
50-75   255     143     31      255     0       0
75-100  255     0       0       255     0       0
```

So for example,

- If I send the double 0.0 I would get 255,255,255 returned
- If I send the double 0.5 I would get 145 221 249 returned
- If I send the double 1.0 I would get 0 255 0 returned

I guess it would possibly need six different part to allow for the six ranges?

Example of concept in long form:

```
private string RGB(double value) //pass value 0.0 - 100.0
    {
        if(value == 0)
        {
            return ("255,255,255");
        }
        if(value >= 0 && value <= 1)
        {
            //calculate rgb value between  164,242,243  and   125,200,255 
            return ("something between 164,242,243 and 125,200,255");
        }
        //more if's here
        return ("nothing found");
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried implementing it? Please provide [mcve] of your code and explain what problems you are facing with it.

Comment: Read about [interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation) and try implement it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;

namespace ConsoleApp2

{

    class Program
    {

        static void Main()
        {
            Color color =  RGBScale.AverageColor(.5F);

        }
    }
    public class RGBScale
    {
        //each row is defined as follows
        //low range, high range,   Ra,      Ga,      Ba,      Rb,      Gb,      Bb,
        public static List<List<int>> table = new List<List<int>>() {
            new List<int>() {0, 1, 165, 242, 243, 125, 200, 255},
            new List<int>() {1, 25, 0, 255, 0, 63, 82, 0},
            new List<int>() {25, 50, 63, 82, 0, 255, 143, 31},
            new List<int>() {50, 75, 255, 143, 31, 255, 0, 0},
            new List<int>() {75, 100, 255, 0, 0, 255, 0,0}
        };

        public static Color AverageColor(float index)
        {
            int red = 255;
            int blue = 255;
            int green = 255;

            foreach (List<int> row in table)
            {
                if (index <= row[1])
                {
                    double start = row[0];
                    double end = row[1];
                    double scale = (index - start) / (end - start); 
                    red = (int)Math.Round(scale * (row[5] - row[2]) + row[2]);
                    green = (int)Math.Round(scale * (row[6] - row[3]) + row[3]);
                    blue = (int)Math.Round(scale * (row[7] - row[4]) + row[4]);
                    break;
                }

            }
            return Color.FromArgb(red, green, blue);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Here is a sample of the code running on a windows form

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Buttons
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        const int ROWS = 5;
        const int COLS = 20;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
        }
        public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            new MyButton(ROWS, COLS, this);
        }


    }
    public class MyButton : PictureBox
    {
        const int WIDTH = 50;
        const int HEIGHT = 50;
        const int SPACE = 5;
        const int BORDER = 20;

        public static List<List<MyButton>> buttons { get; set; }
        public static List<MyButton> buttonList { get; set; }
        public Form1 form1;
        public int row { get; set; }
        public int col { get; set; }
        public MyButton()
        {
        }
        public MyButton(int rows, int cols, Form1 form1)
        {
            int count = 1;
            buttons = new List<List<MyButton>>();
            buttonList = new List<MyButton>();

            this.form1 = form1;
            for(int row = 0; row < rows; row++)
            {
                List<MyButton> newRow = new List<MyButton>();
                buttons.Add(newRow);
                for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++)
                {
                    MyButton newButton = new MyButton();
                    newButton.Height = HEIGHT;
                    newButton.Width = WIDTH;
                    newButton.Top = row * (HEIGHT + SPACE) + BORDER;
                    newButton.Left = col * (WIDTH + SPACE) + BORDER;
                    newButton.row = row;
                    newButton.col = col;
                    newButton.BackColor = RGBScale.AverageColor(count++);
                    newRow.Add(newButton);
                    buttonList.Add(newButton);
                    newButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(Button_Click);
                    form1.Controls.Add(newButton);
                }
            }
        }
        public void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MyButton button = sender as MyButton;
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Pressed Button Row {0} Column {1}", button.row, button.col));

        }

    }
    public class RGBScale
    {
        //each row is defined as follows
        //low range, high range,   Ra,      Ga,      Ba,      Rb,      Gb,      Bb,
        public static List<List<int>> table = new List<List<int>>() {
            new List<int>() {0, 1, 165, 242, 243, 125, 200, 255},
            new List<int>() {1, 25, 0, 255, 0, 63, 82, 0},
            new List<int>() {25, 50, 63, 82, 0, 255, 143, 31},
            new List<int>() {50, 75, 255, 143, 31, 255, 0, 0},
            new List<int>() {75, 100, 255, 0, 0, 255, 0,0}
        };

        public static Color AverageColor(float index)
        {
            int red = 255;
            int blue = 255;
            int green = 255;

            foreach (List<int> row in table)
            {
                if (index <= row[1])
                {
                    double start = row[0];
                    double end = row[1];
                    double scale = (index - start) / (end - start);
                    red = (int)Math.Round(scale * (row[5] - row[2]) + row[2]);
                    green = (int)Math.Round(scale * (row[6] - row[3]) + row[3]);
                    blue = (int)Math.Round(scale * (row[7] - row[4]) + row[4]);
                    break;
                }

            }
            return Color.FromArgb(red, green, blue);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

The red is too dark.  Recommend changing last row of table to following : 75, 100, 255, 0, 0, 200, 0,0

Comment: Made a couple of small improvements.  Removed 1st row of table that is not needed.  I'm initializing red, blue, green to 255 which does equivalent.  Then changed '<' to '<=' so that 100 will apply to the last row of table instead of returning the defaults 255,255,255.

Comment: Awesome job, Thanks